# A way to conditionally chain functions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, methods

What im trying to do is to write a universal function for retrieving items from database using ***redis-om-node***.
It uses this chain of methods to specify what items we want to retrieve

```
const items = await repositoryObject
.search()
.where("property1")
.match(query)
.or("property2")
.match(query)
.or("property3")
.match(query)
.return.all();
```

Is there a way I could loop through array of properties to make this chain write itself like:

```
const items = await repositoryObject
.search()[loop outputed chain].return.all();
```

Im aware that I can just run raw search but I want to know am I missing something about javascript objects

Comment: Possible, but what you have already is quite succinct and easy to understand already. Abstracting it out would take a bit of code and make it harder to make sense of at a glance. Not worth it unless there are many such repetitive chains, IMO

Comment: I have no idea why this was tagged [[tag:eval]]. Definitely don't use `eval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you could create an array of objects which contain the properties and corresponding queries that you want to use, and then loop through it like this:

```
const queries = [{ property: "property1", query: query1 }, { property: "property2", query: query2 }, { property: "property3", query: query3 }]; // etc

let result = repositoryObject.search();

for (const { property, query } of queries) {
  result = result.where(property).match(query);
}

return result.return.all();
```

You could get more fancy and use `reduce` if you wanted to:

```
// queries is as above

return queries.reduce((object, { property, query }) => object.property(property).match(query), repositoryObject.search()).return.all();
```

or use the `forEach` method on the array to loop. Basically you can loop all the ways you have in normal Javascript - you just have to use it to construct a property chain of the form you showed us.